# Error message "Call to a member function query() on a non-object"

Tags: php, mysql

In the following code, I am trying to check if the username entered has been used or not by counting the username.

```
<?php
$hostname = 'aaa';
$username = 'bbb';
$password = 'ccc';
$prefix = "";
$dbna = 'ddd';
$username11 = $_POST['username'];
try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbna", $username, $password);
$nRows = $pdo->query("SELECT count(Username) FROM Users WHERE Username ='$username11'")->fetchColumn(); 
if($nRows)
{
echo '<span style="color: red;">The username <b>'.$username11.'</b> is already in use.    </span>';
}
else
{
echo 'OK';
}
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The error is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/check.php on line 10
```

I looked for the solution for this error but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pdo->query
```

should be:

```
$dbh->query
```